# Should I use an Angular Component as an Injectable Service?

Tags: angular, angular-components

Which is the best practice to use in Angular when I need some method for a component that it is hosted on another component?
Should I use the component who has the method as a service itself, specifying it on the providers specifications of the module or create a dedicated *.service.ts* file to this operation and inject it on the modules declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been flagged by at least one user as "opinion" based,
but I disagree.

Angular has the specific roles of "Component" and "Service" and your 'shared method' clearly (to me) is in the category of a Service.

The reason that this tends to become unclear is because many developers tend to put service-like logic directly into components. That's probably because it's easy to do, and because a lot of simplistic examples available on the web reinforce it.

However, if you take the view the a Component is actually a "Controller" in MVC terms, then you will see that logic in a Component that manipulates data does not belong there.

So, short answer....extract the method to a Service.

Comment: I had a component with one publisher of BehaviorSubject and other component subscribed to listen every wrong request made on the first one. When injecting the component on another one as a service, only the first subject was caught by the observer every time, extracting the method publisher of the subject to a segregated service class helped the first component to catch all the values on the observable type. Your answer helped a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a unique method on two different components, the common path is abstracting that method in a `shared.service.ts` or something like that and then inject it trough dependency injection on both components `.ts`

Answer (score 0):

### If in the same module:

You can just use `<app-user-list></app-user-list>` to use a component in an other one.

### In a different module:

If you're looking to reuse some of your components or services indifferent part of your application, you should use what's called a shared module. You can then import that module in any module of your choice to get access to it's components or services.

Here's a list of things you could find in a shared module:

- navigation component
- confirmation dialog component
- order-list component
- notification service